# Why is Typescript coercing my keyof type to a never type and how do I fix it?

Tags: typescript, coercion

Sorry if this is a dupe, I'm new to TypeScript and am having trouble figuring out if similar-looking questions are related because a lot of them are doing very complex things. Anyway the problem is, I have a relatively simple setup that TS is choking on because it's coercing a type to `never` and I don't really understand why it's doing that. Here's the setup:

```js
interface BigObject {
  foo: {
    a?: string
    b?: string
  }
  bar: {
    c?: string
    d?: string
  }
}

const instance: BigObject = {
  foo: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
  },
  bar: {
    c: "c",
    d: "d",
  }
}

function metafunction(bigObjProp: keyof BigObject) {
  type LittleObject = BigObject[typeof bigObjProp]
  // IDE hints show this ^^ as being correct, i.e. either of the two "sub interfaces"

  return function (littleObjProp: keyof LittleObject) { // <== littleObjProp is resolving to never
    return function (bigObject: BigObject) {
      const littleObject = bigObject[bigObjProp]
      return littleObject ? littleObject[littleObjProp] : "fallback value"
    }
  }
}

const firstClosure = metafunction("foo")
const secondClosure = firstClosure("a") // <== Argument of type "a" is not assignable to type "never"
const value = secondClosure(instance)
```

My expectation is that the value of `value` will be "a".

I don't understand why `littleObjProp` resolves to `never`. My assumption would be that because `LittleObject` is built from the type of the argument passed in to `metafunction`, TS would pick which "sub interface" to use for any given invocation. So, for example, when I call `metafunction("foo")`, TS would set `LittleObject` to `{ a?: string; b?: string }` and thus, when I call `firstClosure("a")`, it would say, "ah yes, 'a' is indeed a valid key of LittleObject, carry on". It can't do this, however, because it always thinks that `keyof LittleObject` means `never`.

Can someone help me understand 1) why it's doing this and 2) how to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I realize it's a weird setup but I'm dealing with some weird React libraries and this is just where I am at the moment. Please assume I have to keep the same overall structure of a function returning a function returning a function as seen in the example. Also I would really appreciate it if you could keep your answer as simple as possible since I am a bit new to TS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `metafunction` generic.

As you have it above, there's no generic type. To be safe `firstClosure` is only going to take a key that `foo` and `bar` have in common, but they have no key in common so `never` is the only possible parameter. If you were to give them a key in common, `firstClosure` would be typed to accept that.

```js
interface BigObject {
  foo: {
    a?: string
    b?: string
    f?: string   // Added
  }
  bar: {
    c?: string
    d?: string
    f?: string   // Added
  }
}

const instance: BigObject = {
  foo: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    f: "f",
  },
  bar: {
    c: "c",
    d: "d",
    f: "f",
  }
}

const secondClosure = firstClosure("f")   // "f" is the only valid value
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELAOYHkBGArCBMZAbwChlkYB7agLlIsuTgH4GBnMKUDJynO2RceIPsypCRvJgF8mOOFAbkJCKdxkSAJhtHjmMPVuTz5ZBNRBdkoLnBBIG6bPkLEAvI0o1635nAMAERwQQA0-Mg4wTjhkTDBMHGUshECSiqRCMEIyczawdp5Pol5ZmRkMACujmDAVsgAthBgcNW19SAAFDiYuHgAClDUAA4MANYQAJ7UMGh9bkQAlP5gUyMoADLAYGAANhD97sheLkdEANprG7NRC4PDIwC6TAD0r8gAkgAiAKLIAAtQGAOMIAdQAO7IMBA0EAPThLFBOAgvGQligUHcYVsADoILjkKiYdBkLcSdCIdRkEEOFUcLZwNB4EgOEEKpQsWAqlAQFQakROsgunsdvtDvghqMJtNbttdgdzmAViRkO9kAAeDxeUUKiUPUa2UFYjjUPYANzRYGpIAg5ugkS5PL57UFDR693czk9y38aisNl14qVJzurgIl164alz0inJazuQQcVi2IrCTYpTEbAF2T+pjT2QiTgez2igQ42Q5pLVQg7Ik8hSZHMlmsxBgwCgXAAwntqHSsaHmq1XXUrF0gr4gksLAHiBxCFZtL3+zyUF4O12wCuBxAJ0kVuqtV4AIJQDBVZrgMlza4oEJBI3IEDUYhwDgcTAgOA4A7Q6l3jStr2lA7KtjY1Z7LWoYLq2y59ruXR2K0jgQDOQA)

By adding a generic, you can convince Typescript to keep the type information as a property of `metafunction` and `firstClosure` each, which gives your closure the type you're looking for.

```js
function metafunction<T extends keyof BigObject>(bigObjProp: T) {
  type LittleObject = BigObject[T]

  return function (littleObjProp: keyof LittleObject) {
    return function (bigObject: BigObject) {
      const littleObject = bigObject[bigObjProp]
      return littleObject[littleObjProp] ?? "fallback value"
    }
  }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELAOYHkBGArCBMZAbwChlkYB7agLlIsuTgH4GBnMKUDJynO2RceIPpQC+THHCgNyzZAiEje-ZABMV3NZLJSyCaiC7JQXOCCQN02fIWIBeRpRr0XzOAwBEcbwBp1HB8cAKYJQIFZeXUEHwQwxQ0fDUTkKQMYAFcrMGBjZABbCDA4bNz8kAAeABVkCAAPSBANDmQAawgAT2oYNExcAiIAPgAKHAH8AAUoagAHBhqASg8wLrmUABlgMDAAGwhBh2RnWyOiAG0agF0mAHo75ABJABEAUWQAC1AwNo5P6gAd2QYG+bQAeuCWG0cBBeEpqFAoA5-GYAHQQNH1HafaDIXog3EgwHUZDeDhZHBmcDQeBIDjeMhMZFgLJQEBUHJESrIUZ7Hb7Q7TWYLDrdAnbXYHc5gFYkZAPZBVRzOflSoV4GbzMxtZEcah7ABu8LApJAEEN0HULLZHPK3IK40mQzANmdDjl6koRhMxDVgplJ2QEzsLouIcGWrmt0UlBt7OQ-ul9kuSY1UeuyFYrDJ8D2exkCHayENcD2WQgjMUUj0Bh9phgwCgXAAwntqBTkQAxWhB4qle15YyjbxubxLQzGUwcQjGDRtjtsiA90nORvNsALzvL2gjvwT+vEUvlner4Szlpbpcr0bmUpWCATye+qhN1vt7eoWR9kplLlDkARxkKBx2facL3nD8ly-KAg3Xd9F2RGCRwSA8pyPMsKxgoMZx9SDEIgZC70sJAJyAA)

Comment: You rock! Thanks so much!